# Show RAM usage Cisco 2960

Tags: cisco, switch, ethernet, cisco-ios

I'm trying to see how much RAM is being used by each switch.

The switch is a cisco WS-C2960-24TT-L IOS version 12.2.

This is what I am seeing from the switch when I run the show version command.

> cisco WS-C2960-24TT-L (PowerPC405) processor (revision R0) with 65536K bytes of memory.

I've seen another 2960 Version 12.2 which showed the ram usage, however, this was a 2960-24TC-L switch.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: did you try "show memory"? It works on IOS 12.2(55)SE7 which is pretty close to your 12.2.(55)SE5 version.

Comment: I did, here's the response.

> ast-105-p01-sw3#show memory
                
Head    Total(b)     Used(b)     Free(b)   Lowest(b)  Largest(b)Processor    26F0E6C    22335808    14440252     7895556     6691152     7570392
I/O    2C00000     4194304     2337976     1856328     18020481855232
Driver te    1800000     1048576          44     1048532     10485321048532

Comment: It shows processor, I/O and Driver Te, but are any of these RAM related? The switch has 65MB of RAM according to the  "show version" command

Comment: Please, never use an image to show text. Copy the text, paste it into your question, and use the Preformatted Text feature (`{}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use command:

```
#show proc mem
```

you will get output like:

```
Processor Pool Total:   43953664 Used:   12967924 Free:   30985740
      I/O Pool Total:    8388608 Used:    2998796 Free:    5389812
```

or for more detailed you can use:

```
#show memory summary
                Head    Total(b)     Used(b)     Free(b)   Lowest(b)  Largest(b)
Processor    1652A00    43953664    12972664    30981000    29707060    30031048
      I/O   80000000     8388608     2998920     5389688     3992572     4660984
[output omitted]
```

Total = the total amount of memory available after the system image loads and builds its data structures.

Used = the amount of memory currently allocated.

Free = the amount of memory currently free.

Lowest = the lowest amount of free memory recorded by the router since it was last booted.

Largest = the largest free memory block currently available.

Comment: Doesn't Processor only show the CPU usage?

Comment: you can use #show memory summary for more detailed information.

Comment: I was hoping for a command that could give me something like 

cisco WS-C2960-24TT-L (PowerPC405) processor (revision R0) with 61536K/4000k bytes of memory. 

As I want to scrape this information with Python to get an idea of how much RAM is being used per switch.

Comment: 61536K/4000k doesn't mean how much memory is free. Those two number combined give you total memory size.

Comment: But does the second number not mean the amount of memory that is currently being used?

Comment: It tells you how much Dynamic RAM (DRAM) and Packet memory are installed in your router. Some platforms use a fraction of their DRAM as Packet memory. So you have to add both numbers to find the amount of DRAM available on your router.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this in our local lab with default configurations on the
switch. I saw that 83.4% of I/O pool was used with default config on the
switch.

Then I added some running config  and I observed 94.5% used.

SO this is how it works and I guess nothing to worry about.